# Perf Error: The sys_perf_event_open() syscall returned with 3 (No such process) for event

Tags: docker, profiling, performancecounter, perf

I am using perf stat on process mode (-p option) to count some events of an application. I first send some requests with a load generator and then use perf stat to get the measurements. My process is a docker container (so it creates many pids while running load generator and perf).

By searching a bit the issue i think without being 100% certain that this error is caused cause some pids that perf stat is monitoring are terminated (before opening the event) and instead of ignoring them it raises an error.

I tried bypassing it by starting first perf stat and then the load generator. The issue started happening less times but it was still present.

I am kinda confused about this and i would really appreciate some help if someone has encountered something similar :)

Edit - Additional infos:

i am using perf_4.9 an example command i use is the following:

`perf stat -e r8024,LLC-load-misses,LLC-store-misses -p $PID sleep 20`

i try to count some similar events with the above about L1,L2,L3 cache.

The load generator i use is wrk2. The load generator runs for about 2mins while in parallel i run 5 perf stat commands (the perf stat commands are serial not parallel with each other). The perf error i stated is not observed in the same perf stat command but is kinda random on every run.

Comment: It would be a great help if you show the `perf stat` command you use along with some information about how you run the load generator.

Comment: @ArnabjyotiKalita i edited my question with some additional info, let me know if they are usefull :)